# Why is there a separate equals method for sets?

Tags: c#, equals

In C Sharp .NET there is a `Equals` method and a `SetEquals` method. Where is the difference?

Coming from Java, my first thought was that `SetEquals` is not necessary, just use the `Equals` method for all objects.

Comment: you mean this `ISet<T>.SetEquals` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412096.aspx?

Comment: i think documentation is pretty clear on what is the difference.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`SetEquals` doesn't obey the same contract as `Equals`. In particular it's not symmetric, as the argument is just `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `ISet<T>`. This allows you to check for set equality while only having *one* set. Consider:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
HashSet<int> intSet = new HashSet<int>(intList);
```

Now we can use:

```
Console.WriteLine(intSet.SetEquals(intList));
```

... but we couldn't implement `Equals` in the same way without enforcing the same behaviour on `List<int>` and every other `IEnumerable<T>` implementation.

Even if we restricted it to other sets, there's the interesting question of what equality really means. For example, consider two `HashSet<string>` sets which contain the same strings, but have different equality comparers. (Maybe one is case-sensitive and one isn't.) Are those equal, or not? `SetEquals` manages to avoid such philosophical questions by avoiding trying to be too general.

What about a `HashSet<int>` and a `SortedSet<int>`? Could they ever be equal? They can have the same values - but the ordering of one is undefined.

Overall, the ideas of `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` are too broad in my view. Often you want a particular *type* of equality - and often it makes no sense to compare objects for equality in the first place. This could easily form the subject of a completely different rant, but in the meantime I'm at least glad that .NET didn't try to apply this overly-broad idea to collections. The ability to use `SetEquals` with a well-defined meaning is more useful, IMO.

Answer (score 14):

`HashSet<T>.SetEquals` determines if the HashSet contains the same elements as a given `IEnumerable<T>`. But why should it return true if the types are diffferent?

```
HashSet<int> h = new HashSet<int>();
h.Add(0);
h.Add(1);
int[] ints = new[] { 0, 1, 1, 0 };
h.SetEquals(ints); // true, ignores duplicates because it's a set
h.Equals(ints); // false, correct because not even the same types
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx):

> The SetEquals method ignores duplicate entries and the order of
>   elements in the other parameter.....

Since `HasetSet<T>` does not override `Equals` it uses the one inherited from object which just compares references. So if two objects are not the same reference it returns `false`.

Answer (score 8):

- `Equals` would test if two `HashSet`s are the same object.
- [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx) takes in a `IEnumerable<T>`, What it does is: *"The SetEquals method ignores duplicate entries and the order of elements in the other parameter."*

So `SetEquals` is for testing to see if you loaded a IEnumerable in to a HashSet, would it generate the same HashSet as your source.

Answer (score 3):

`Equals` checks for reference equality between the two and `SetEquals` will check the elements on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

SetEquals:

> Checks if the HashSet contains the same elements as a given **IEnumerable`<T>`**.
>
> SetEquals method treats the second collection as though it has no duplicate elements. If duplicate elements are present, the two collections may still be considered equal.

Equals:

> Equals is actually a Referential test

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
SortedSet<string> stringSet = new SortedSet<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

bool a = stringSet.SetEquals(stringList );
// See if the two collections contain the same elements.
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ISet<T>.SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412096.aspx) implementation

> Determines whether the current set and the specified collection contain the same elements.

The the [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) implementation inherited from `object`

> is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method.

The inherited [ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) implementation,

> Determines whether the specified Object instances are the same instance.

---

In paticular, note that the `IEnumerable<T>` sequence passed to `SetEquals` could have one or more instances of every member of the set, in any order, and `SetEquals` would still return true.

---

If you want to confirm that two sequences contain the exactly the same members in the same order you can use the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int> setA= new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>();
            setA.Add(1);
            System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int> setB= new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>();
            setB.Add(1);


            Console.WriteLine("Equals method returns {0}", setA.Equals(setB));
            Console.WriteLine("SetEquals method returns {0}", setA.SetEquals(setB));


            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
```

Produces output : 
Equals method returns False
SetEquals method returns True

The equals method therefore seems to be a test on referential equality.